# Equal class misunderstanding

Tags: haskell, typeclass

- I have my own data type to represent nodes and edges of a graph as follows:

  ```
  data Node a = Node a deriving (Show, Eq)

  data Label a = Label a deriving (Show)

  data Cost = CostI Int | CostF Float deriving (Show)

  data Edge label node = Edge (Label label, (Node node,Node node), Cost) deriving (Show)
  ```
- Now, I create a function to check whether an edge contains 2 nodes or not as follows:

  ```
  isEdge:: (Eq n) => (Edge l n) -> (Node n, Node n) -> Bool
  isEdge (Edge (_, (n1,n2), _)) (n3, n4) = result
       where result = (n1 == n3) && (n2 == n4)
  ```
- The function works well, the problem here is **if I remove (Eq n) from the function**, it fails. So, why is that, even though in the declaration above I declared `Node` as deriving from Eq class?

  ```
  data Node a = Node a deriving (Show, Eq)
  ```

Comment: Just a stylistic point, there no point in writing `data A = A (x, y, z)` rather than `data A = A x y z` and the first version actually uses more space and is more awkward to pattern match on (there is an extra layer of indirection), `data Edge label node = Edge (Label label) (Node node) (Node node) Cost` works just fine.

Comment: Also, you don't need to look inside the pairs of nodes to compare for equality -- you can just write `result = (n1,n2) == (n3,n4)`.  Finally, it's a bit unstylistic to name your type variables `label` and `node` -- usually they'd just be `a` and `b`, or, if you want, something like `n` and `l`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Eq` instance GHC derives for `Node a` is something like this:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Node a) where
    (Node x) == (Node y) = x == y
    (Node x) /= (Node y) = x /= y
```

You can view the generated code by compiling with `-ddump-deriv`.  The `Eq a` constraint is needed for obvious reasons.  So, GHC couldn't infer an instance of `Eq` for, say, `Node (a -> b)` since functions can't be compared.

However, the fact that GHC can't infer an instance of `Eq` for `Node a` for **some** `a` doesn't mean it will stop you from constructing a values of type `Node a` where `a` isn't an equality type.

---

If you wanted to stop people from constructing non-comparable `Node`s, you could try putting a constraint like this:

```
data Eq a => Node a = Node a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

But now GHC tells us we need a compiler pragma:

```
Illegal datatype context (use -XDatatypeContexts): Eq a =>
```

OK, let's add it to the top of our file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
```

Now compile:

```
/tmp/foo.hs:1:41: Warning: -XDatatypeContexts is deprecated: It was widely
considered a misfeature, and has been removed from the Haskell language.
```

The problem is that now *every* function using `Node`s will need an `Eq` class constraint, which is annoying (your functions still need the constraint!).  (Also, if your user wants to create `Node`s using a non-equality type but never tests them for equality, what's the problem?)

---

There's actually a way to get GHC to do what you want, however: Generalized Algebraic Data Types ([GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Node a where
  Node :: Eq a => a -> Node a
```

This looks just like your original definition, except that it emphasizes the `Node` *value constructor* (the one formerly on the right hand side of the data declaration) is just a function, which you can add constraints to.  Now GHC knows that only equality types can be put into `Node`s, and unlike our earlier attempted solution, we can make new functions that don't need a constraint:

```
fromNode :: Node a -> a
fromNode (Node x) = x
```

We can still derive `Eq` and `Show` instances, but with a slightly different syntax:

```
deriving instance Eq   (Node a)
deriving instance Show (Node a)
```

(Hence the StandaloneDeriving pragma above.)

For this to work, GHC also requires us to add a `Show` constraint to our GADT (if you look at the generated code again, you'll see the constraints are now gone):

```
data Node a where
  Node :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> Node a
```

And now we can take the `Eq` constraint off `isEdge`, since GHC can infer it!

(This is definitely overkill for such a simple situation -- again, if people want to construct nodes with functions inside them, why shouldn't they?  However, GADTs are extremely useful in pretty similar situations when you want to enforce certain properties of your data types.  See [a cool example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT)).

---

EDIT (from the future): you can also write

```
data Node a = (Eq a, Show a) => Node a
```

but you still need to enable GADT extensions and derive instances separately.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888720/alternative-for-deprecated-xdatatypecontext#comment19135458_13888788).

Comment: Interesting with GADTs, using type constraint in every function is really annoying. I will take a look at GADTs. Thanks @Fixnum

Comment: I'm curious as to the community's thoughts on this.  Other than the loss of generality and portability to non-GHC compilers, are there other reasons to eschew this "solution"?  (Proliferation of constraints really isn't a problem as far as I know, unlike, say, proliferation of instances, and can be useful documentation.)

Comment: @Fixnum one big issue is that it's no longer possible to create `Node`s for types without the appropriate class.  For `Eq` this might not be an issue, but for `Show` it likely would be.  Another downside is increased memory usage; a `Node` must store an extra pointer for every type class mentioned in the GADT.  If you have a lot of nodes, this could be significant.

Answer (score 5):

When you add a `deriving` clause to a data declaration, the derived clause will include any necessary constraints for the type variable in scope at the declaration.  In this case, `deriving Eq` will create essentially the following instance:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Node a) where
    (Node a) == (Node b) = a == b
    (Node a) /= (Node b) = a /= b
```

Any derived `Eq` instance will depend upon the Eq instance of types that appear to the right of the data constructor.

This is because there's really no other way to derive an `Eq` instance automatically.  Two values are equal if they have the same type and all their components are equal.  So you need to be able to test the components for equality.  In order to generically test a polymorphic component for equality, you need an `Eq` instance.

This is true not just for `Eq`, but for all the derived classes.  For example this code

```
toStr :: Edge l n -> String
toStr = show
```

won't work without adding the constraint `(Show l, Show n)`.  Without that constraint, the function to show an `Edge` doesn't know what to call to show its internal Labels and Nodes.