# Alternative for deprecated -XDatatypeContext?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I want to define a tree like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
class Node a where
  getContent :: (Num a) => a

data (Node a) => Tree a = Leaf a
                        | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

-XDatatypeContexts is deprecated now. Is it possible to do something similar without it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you *sure* datatype contexts actually did what you think it did? It was [deprecated because it was basically useless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7438600/157360) and widely considered a misfeature, since all it did was force you to add extra constraints without providing any guarantees about types beyond what you'd have had without it.

The replacement, such as it is, that actually *does* something useful, is [GADT syntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-algebraic-data-types-gadts). The equivalent of your type would look like this:

```
data Tree a where
    Leaf :: (Node a) => a -> Tree a
    Branch :: (Node a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

In this case, you need the `Node` constraint when creating a `Tree` value, but when pattern matching on a `Tree` value you also get an automatic guarantee that a `Node` instance exists, making the instance available without even needing it in the type of the function receiving `Tree a` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much! Though I think you mean 
Branch :: (Node a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a

Comment: @Jake: No--it works just like a function type signature, so the last `Tree a` is the resulting data type. `a -> Tree a -> Tree a` would only have one sub-tree. Compare the type of the `Branch` constructor you have currently.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need GADT syntax for this. You can also write `data Tree a = Node a => Leaf a | Node a => Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)`.

Comment: Also, to Jake: What cmccann said would work, but are you completely sure it's what you want? The usual approach is to put constraints on functions that use `Tree`, rather than on the constructor -- e.g. `foo :: Node a => Tree a -> ...` -- and it has some important advantages over this one. Is there a reason it doesn't work for you in this case?

Comment: @shachaf: To talk at someone, talk @ them. This will put a notification in their inbox, as this comment self-demonstrates.