# How to state that a type variable in a newtype statement is of a type that belongs to some type class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

Suppose that I have this newtype:

```
newtype SomeType a = SomeType { foo :: OtherType a }
```

I want to ensure that `a` is showable (belongs to the type class `Show x`).

How do I ensure that? (Is it even possible?)

Bonus points: am I using the terminology correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with the `DatatypeContexts` extension, but it is strongly discouraged:

```
newtype Show a => SomeType a = SomeType { foo :: Maybe a }
```

It is recommended to put the constraint on the functions that use `SomeType` or use GADTs. See the answers to these questions for more information.

[Alternative for deprecated -XDatatypeContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888720/alternative-for-deprecated-xdatatypecontext)

[DatatypeContexts Deprecated in Latest GHC: Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438600/datatypecontexts-deprecated-in-latest-ghc-why)

Basically, it doesn't add anything useful and it makes you have to put constraints where they wouldn't otherwise be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate @David's answer in a small example, imagine you're implementing another incarnation of a balanced binary tree. Of course keys must be `Ord`ered, so you add a constraint to the type declaration:

```
data Ord k => Tree k v = Tip | Bin k v (Tree k v) (Tree k v)
```

Now this constraint infects every other signature **everywhere** you're using this type, even when you don't really need to order keys. It wouldn't probably be a bad thing (after all, you'll need to order them at least somewhere – otherwise, you aren't really using this `Tree`) and it definitely doesn't break the code, but still makes it less readable, adds noise and distracts from important things.

```
empty :: Ord k => Tree k v

singleton :: Ord k => k -> v -> Tree k v

find :: Ord k => (v -> Bool) -> Tree k v -> Maybe v

instance Ord k => Functor (Tree k)
```

In all of these signatures the constraint could be omitted without any problems.